# Spring-JPA insert operation exception while using merge function

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Person class

```
package com.example.springjpa.demojpa.entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;
private String location;
private Date birth_date;

public Person() {};



public Person(String name, String location, Date birth_date) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
}



public Person(int id, String name, String location, Date birth_date) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
}



public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public Date getBirth_date() {
    return birth_date;
}

public void setBirth_date(Timestamp birth_date) {
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n Person [name=" + name + ", location=" + location + ", birth_date=" + birth_date + "]";
}

}
```

PersonJpaDao class

```
package com.example.springjpa.demojpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.springjpa.demojpa.entity.Person;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonJpaDao {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public Person findById(int id) {
    return em.find(Person.class, id);
}


public Person insert(Person person){
    return em.merge(person);
}

public Person update(Person person){
    return em.merge(person);
}
}
```

Main Class

```
 package com.example.springjpa.demojpa;


import java.util.Date;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.example.springjpa.demojpa.entity.Person;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoJpaApplication.class, args);
}

@Autowired
PersonJpaDao personJpaDao;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    logger.info("Person yBy Id {}", personJpaDao.findById(1));

    logger.info("Update 10003 -> {}", 
            personJpaDao.update(new Person("Pieter", "Utrecht", new Date())));

}
}
```

When I run the main function, find and update are working fine but for insert operation which has the same code as update is throwing an exception as follows:

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.PERSON(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into person (birth_date, location, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-196]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: How are you executing insert, you only show findById and update.

Comment: update updates if the id is already present else it inserts the new value;

Comment: I found the error since the I used the annotation @GeneratedValue the insert was conflicting with the id that already existed in the database

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but what I found it was like it is clashing with the primary key like some data is already present with some (primary key 20) and entity manager is also 
making it  to the same primary key(20) because you are using merge method to update and create both, Hence it is leading to a clash of previously existing and newly created through merge method try to give id in the constructor or remove the data